# How to display data to view from db after insertion? [L5.2]

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, xampp, laravel-5

what I am trying to do here is after the insertion I want to display the data in the same page without refreshing the page

ROUTES

Route::post('viewBook/{bookId}',    'CommentsController@insertcomment');

//there's {bookId} cause of this http://localhost:8000/viewBook/1

CONTROLLER

```
public function insertcomment(Request $request)
{

    $commenter = Auth::user()->id;
    $comments   = new Comments;
    $comments->comment = $request->input('mycomment');
    $comments->commenter = $commenter;
    $comments->save(); //insert success

    //getting the data
    $data=DB::table('comments')
        ->select('comment')
        ->get();
    return response()->json($data,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the data from DB again, just return inserted `Comment` object:

```
$commenter = Auth::user()->id;
$comment = new Comments;
$comment->comment = $request->input('mycomment');
$comment->commenter = $commenter;
$comment->save(); //insert success

return response()->json($comment, true);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply :) how can I display it to view?

Comment: @donnah if you want to display it without reloading the page, use AJAX for that for that. Laravel will return JSON object which you can use to display just inserted comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation.

1. In http://localhost:8000/viewBook/1. You should send a AJAX request to Route::post('viewBook/{bookId}', 'CommentsController@insertcomment');
2. Then get response from server for append to current comments HTML section. The response like @Alexey Mezenin answer